# How do I create controls in child class in SWT. And then working with it in that parent class

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I need to create property tab with error view and data view (should I call it view?) in it. I want to do something like this. I have two classes. First:AbstractContentProvider:

```
 abstract public class AbstractContentProvider {
          Text errtext;
    public void createControls(Composite parent){
        super.createControls(Composite parent);
        StackLayout sl=new StackLayout();
        parent.setLayout(sl);
        Composite pane=new Composite(parent,SWT.NONE);
        //pane init code is ommitted
        errtext=new Text(pane,SWT.WRAP);
        sl.topControl=text;
    }
    public void setErrText(String text){
        errText=text;
    }
}
```

So this is my code for abstractClass, which makes a little text and StackLayout for changing views around. Here's createControls from second (child) class:

```
public class ContentProvider extends AbstractContentProvider{
    public void createControls(Composite parent){
        super.createControls(Composite parent);
        //this methods are omitted, but they just creating swt toolbar and table
        createToolBar(parent);
        createTable(parent);

        setErrText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

There can be different content on the property page, but, there is always the same errText view should be created for each tab. How do I add data view from child class and then work with it by calling methods of parent class?

Comment: Maybe you put things, that are in common into the parent class. And put things, that are different into the child class? (Inheritance)

Comment: So I did. Common thing is error text view(and it's in parent class). And data view is different for each child class. But I need to change between them by calling parent methods(in this case method that changes top control of a StackLayout) or something like that.

Comment: if you really have subclassed you can easily say myChildInstance.setErrText("String");

Comment: Well, I can call setErrText("String"); from child class. But that's not what I want. I want create tables in my child class for this tab, and then call method from parent and change the element that gonne be shown. For example, I've created table, but I can't show it for this specific element,then I'm gonna need to show an error screen. I call a method from parent class(that's not a problem). And layout changes its topControl. But I don't know how to tell parent class that this tables(created by child class) even exist and how i can swap them in my layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think i still didn't get your question clear :-$

so maybe you tell me if i'm going to the right direction ^^

keep your common part as private variable - then you can access the parent easily...

```
private Object commonPart; //i don't know it's class
public class ContentProvider extends AbstractContentProvider{
    public void createControls(Composite parent, Object commonPart){
        super.createControls(Composite parent);
        this.commonPart= commonPart;
        //this methods are omitted, but they just creating swt toolbar and table
        createToolBar(parent);
        createTable(parent);

        setText("ERROR");      
        commonPart.doSomething(); //i don't know the common part      
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i answered before you added your comment on the question :-/

Comment: You can 'accept' the solution, if it worked out fine for you ;-)